# INSERT ARRAY TO MYSQL USING PHP WITH JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Please help me to insert this to my database.

```
//Start session
session_start();

//database connection
require_once 'connection.php';

$data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST), true);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    $prefix = strtoupper($data[$key]['prefix']);
    $fullname= strtoupper($data[$key]['fullname']);
    $position= strtoupper($data[$key]['position']);

    $result= connect("INSERT INTO `register_info` (prefix, fullname, position) VALUES ('$prefix','$fullname','$position')");

}

 if($result){
    echo json_encode(true);
 }else{
     echo json_encode(false);
 }
```

I Think there's an error in $result.. but I don't know what is that?
Please help me guys.

Comment: Check for errors/bugs in your `connect()` function.

Comment: first check $data with print_r() ,whether values u got or not?

Comment: hi @vignesh i got the value, but it didn't insert to my database...

Comment: Please print your query and check

Comment: please post your connect function

Answer (score 0):

@Aditya, This is my function connect()

```
function connect($sql){

$host = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "";
$db_name = "database";

$db = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to server.');
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db) or die('Database does not exist.');
$result=mysql_query($sql,$db);
return $result;

}
```

There's no error with my connection.